# Auth0 issue: Unable to issue redirect for OAuth 2.0 transaction

Tags: reactjs, auth0

I am trying to use the Auth0 service for a Login development on React. But by the moment I can't figure out why is not working.

This is my code:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
import { Auth0Provider } from '@auth0/auth0-react';

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Auth0Provider
       domain="lafarfalledar.eu.auth0.com"
       clientId="Qwzp67jsGIXKk6Swnj7hUuzLMSiU9mIG"
       redirectUri={window.location.origin}>
      <App />
    </Auth0Provider>
  </React.StrictMode>
);

reportWebVitals();
```

And this is the error that appears:

> Unable to issue redirect for OAuth 2.0 transaction

Could somebody help me?

Comment: What version of the Auth0 React SDK are you using?

Answer (score 7):

For ones using `"@auth0/auth0-react": "^2.0.0"` should be:

```
 <Auth0Provider
    domain="your-domain.us.auth0.com"
    clientId="your_auth0_client_id"
    authorizationParams={{
      redirect_uri: window.location.origin
    }} >
```

Answer (score 2):

You have a Typo there "recirectUri" should be "redirectUri"

Comment: this isn't an answer, its a comment about a typo in the question ..